# Issue with the category Id in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am getting this issue after magento version upgrade from 1.7.2 to 1.9.2 Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Category) with the same id "235" already exist, anyone please suggest what is the issue here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

collection have same id so you can use below code at the end of collection

```
$collection->getSelect()->distinct(true);
```

OR

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in which file?

Comment: You have to add the given code in the file where you had written the Custom collection code.